# Save the outputs of motes in mote memory

Tags: iot, contiki

I am using two motes. one has unicast sender program on it and one has uni-cast receiver program on it. Instead of connecting receiving mote with PC, I want to use batteries for mote power source and I want to save outputs of both motes on its mote memory. How can I save output(printf command outputs) of each mote in mote memory and retrieve later on after completion of experiments. Is there any method(built-in functions, commands or code snippet) available for this
P.S. I am using zolertia z1 motes

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is to use the `xmem` interface. The function prototypes are declared in file `xmem.h`:
https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/dev/xmem.h

For Z1 there's a platform-specific implementation of `xmem` in platform's directory.

If you have never worked with flash memory before, note that the "rewrite" operation is typically not supported by the hardware. You need to erase a whole sector of the flash before you can write anything in that sector. Therefore, the typical usage pattern for dumping sensor data or logs is "write only at the end, never modify".  When the current sector is full, erase the next one and write there, and so until the whole flash is full.

Contiki also the Coffee filesystem, which a higher level interface if you need one.